# Changing background color based on ng-class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hi In a table cell I am trying to change the background color based on the value using ng-class option

```
<style>
  .color-blue {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .color-red {
    background-color: red;
  }

</style>

<td>
  <span ng-class="{'color-blue': r.no > r.aNo,'color-red': r.no , r.aNo}">{{r.no-r.aNo}}</span>
</td>
```

The values are all working fine. With `ng-class` option it is suppose to change the background color. But it displays values but no background color.

Please let me know how to fix it so I can display background color based on positive or negative values.

Thanks

Comment: What is the HTML being rendered though?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put your `ng-class` in `td`

Like this

```
<td  ng-class="{'color-blue': r.no > r.aNo,'color-red': r.no < r.aNo}">
  {{r.no-r.aNo}}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant the following instead (note the `<` instead of a `,`).

```
<td>
    <span ng-class="{'color-blue': r.no > r.aNo,
                     'color-red': r.no < r.aNo}">{{r.no-r.aNo}}</span>
</td>
```